# Problems using React Native for Android on Fedora 25

Tags: java, react-native, fedora-25

I am having problems with React Native for Android running on Fedora 25. I have followed the instructions in the [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) guide.

I have installed all the dependencies such as Node, the React Native CLI, Android Studio and the Android SDK. I have installed the necessary packages in the Android SDK Manager and created an Android Virtual Device.

To test my installation I ran the following commands.

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-android
```

Running the project fails with an SSLHandshakeException (see output snippet below)

```
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
...
```

I suspect this is not so much a React Native problem than a Java Runtime or even a Fedora-specific problem but I'm not sure. There's certainly no mention of this issue in the React Native troubleshooting.

My java version is as follows:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b16)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b16, mixed mode)
```

Incidentally I can access the Gradle URL listed above in a web browser and I am on a home machine so no proxy server to content with.

Thank you.

Comment: i'm having a similar problem, also on F25 using the exact same openJDK version - you can resolve the problem by using oracle jdk, but if you found a solution using openJDK please let us know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem seems to be specific to `1.8.0_111` and/or Fedora 25

upgrading to `1.8.0_121-b14` from the official repository resolved it for me - a `dnf update` should suffice

Comment: You beat me to a solution! Thanks.